# 0 bytes PDF created

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to save from rows from the Powerbuilder datawindow to PDF and it creates 0 bytes files and gives message 'Save Rows As Failed'. Anyone knows why windows 7 and Adobe 9 does this? It work fine on an XP machine

thanks

Answer (score 1):

PowerBuilder uses the open source Ghostscript for its Save As PDF functionality.  You have to have Ghostscript installed and in your path.  PowerBuilder should have created a PDF Printer in your printers list if it has been successfully configured and run.

This post on Stackoverflow has more information on the configuration process:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460930/saving-a-datawindow-as-pdf-in-pb-10-5